# How to display recursive data on jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

```
List<TextualReq> textualReqList = session.createQuery("from TextualReq where parent is null").list();
        for(TextualReq root : textualReqList){
            logger.info("textualReqList ::"+root.getId());
            logger.info("textualReqList ::"+root.getData());
            logger.info("textualReqList ::"+root.getParent());
            logger.info("textualReqList ::"+root.getChildren());

            root.display( "   " );
        }

  public void display( String margin )
           {
              System.out.println( "================="+margin + data );

              for ( TextualReq child : children )
              {
                 child.display( margin + "   " );
              }
           }
```

In Java This function will print the data in below format. I will like to display this data in jsp page. can some one help me how to do I post this data to UI and display recursively. here root.getChildren() is again a private Set children = new HashSet();

```
MyRootData
      MyChild1Data 
         MyGrandchild11Data
         MyGrandchild12Data
            MyGreatGrandchild121Data
         MyGrandchild13Data
      MyChild2Data
         MyGrandchild21Data
         MyGrandchild22Data
   MyRootData
      MyChild1Data 
         MyGrandchild11Data
         MyGrandchild12Data
            MyGreatGrandchild121Data
         MyGrandchild13Data
      MyChild2Data
         MyGrandchild21Data
         MyGrandchild22Data
```

Jsp code that I have is

```
<h3>TextualReq List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listtextualReq}">
    <table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <th width="80">textualReq ID</th>
        <!-- <th width="120">textualReq parent</th> -->
        <!-- <th width="120">textualReq children</th> -->
        <th width="120">textualReq data</th>
        <th width="60">Edit</th>
        <th width="60">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${listtextualReq}" var="textualReq">
        <tr>
            <td>${textualReq.id}</td>
            <%-- <td>${textualReq.parent}</td> --%>
        <%--    <td>${textualReq.children}</td> --%>
            <td>${textualReq.data}</td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value='/edittextualReq/${textualReq.id}' />" >Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value='/removetextualReq/${textualReq.id}' />" >Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

Now it is displaying like
    [image]

Comment: You could embed java code in the JSP, or create a custom tag.

Comment: you can use complete code blocks inside a JSP - see example 4 here: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JSPByExample.html. So put your display method and it's call inside the jsp and add some html in the printing statements

Comment: Do you know the max depth of the recursive stack? If so, you could use nested <c:forEach> loops for each level.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than displaying the data with each recurse, build a String.  I would pass a StringBuilder into the recursive function, then write a getStuff() method that calls that function, and returns the string.  The JSP would simply refer to the getStuff() method.

Comment: Hi Ken Thanks For the response, I'm actually passing list "listtextualReq" to jsp which contains "TextualReq" i.e    public class TextualReq {
    private int                    id; 
    private TextualReq                parent
    private Set<TextualReq> children = new HashSet<TextualReq>();
    private String                  data;
    
    --
    }

Comment: I would still do the recursing in the Java, rather than the JSP.  Recurse to get a flattened list of TextualReq objects, perhaps with an extra property thrown in to define the indentation level.  Alternatively, create a .tag file to display each TextualReq, which calls itself recursively.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it now